# Referring to temporal processes in the second half of a sentence

Tags: present-continuous

Is the second part of this sentence used properly?

> He usually plays tennis very well, but today he is playing bad.

Should the second half of the sentence say "plays"? We consider it as temporal process, don't we?

Comment: What do you mean by "used properly"? Is there anything in particular that you think might be wrong, if so, what?

Comment: @SteveES, not "plays"? We consider it as temporal process, don't we?

Comment: With respect to the verbs: that's a good succinct example showing the difference between simple present (habitual/normal/usual) and continuous (action-in-progress).

Comment: Before we can provide a useful answer, we need to understand why you think _plays_ is correct here. Please use the [edit] link to tell us about the research you have done.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, ok, I was confused with the rule I'd learnt: `we use Present Simple when we're talking about sports commentaries or reviews`

Comment: @P.E.Dant, the matter is given above.

Comment: that is not a good rule. ditch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but today he is playing bad**ly**.

you want to use "**badly**" *(adverb)* to modify "**is playing**" *(verb)* or

> but today his play is bad.

might be used as an alternative, as an *adjective* modifying **play** *(noun)*.

Comment: It would (presumably) be helpful to learners if you could add an explanation as to _why_ an adverb is required.